# Formatting a return string

Tags: java

I am trying to format this return string to display ratings at one decimal place.

```
return String.format(title + "," + genre + "," + releaseYear + "(" + (getRating() == -1 ? "No ratings" : getRating()) + "): " + numOfDeaths + " deaths");
```

I keep getting an error saying too few parameters passed.

Comment: show us full code

Comment: Been a while since I spoke Java but I think format takes multiple arguments. title, genre, releaseYear etc should be arguments. On the other hand, you should probably be able to simply do a "return title + "," + genre + "," + ...

Answer (score 1):

You want java.text.DecimalFormat.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0##");
String result = df.format(getRating());
return String.format(title + "," + genre + "," + releaseYear + "(" + (getRating() == -1 ? "No ratings" : result) + "): " + numOfDeaths + " deaths");
```